# Hibernate3.jar not being loaded in Jboss 6.1 EAP (Migrating from JBOSS 4.3 to 6.1 EAP)

Tags: hibernate, jboss6.x

I'm upgrading jboss 4.3 to jboss 6.1 EAP. The application was using `hibernate3.jar` to load hibernate classes in 4.3. The 6.1 EAP is shared by different applications and the `hibernate4.jar` is available in the global modules of JBOSS (as it is used by other applications). I tried to add `hibernate3.jar` as dependecy in jboss for my application and I added `org.hibernate` as a dependency in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. But I still see hibernate4 classes loaded instead of 3 for my application. How can I make it load only hibernate3?

Below is the log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    at com.arbitron.sms.common.dao.JobDAOImpl.logToAuditProcess(JobDAOImpl.java:388) [mr.jar:]
    at com.arbitron.sms.sample.job.DemoValuesAverageReportJob.execute(DemoValuesAverageReportJob.java:47) [mr.jar:]
    at com.arbitron.sms.common.processing.ReportMessageBean.onMessage(ReportMessageBean.java:41) [mr.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Only recommended that the version of Hibernate shipped with the EAP release.

The below may facilitate the use of Hibernate 3 JPA with your application.

Create the Hibernate 3 module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hibernate" slot="3">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-annotations.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-commons-annotations.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-core.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-entitymanager.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-validator.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="asm.asm"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        <module name="org.javassist"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate" slot="3"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.util"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.jandex"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    </dependencies>
</module
```

NOTE Starting with Hibernate 3.6, hibernate-annotations.jar should NOT be included as the required classes are present in hibernate-core.jar.

Copy the module.xml and the jars specified as resource-root path entries to /org/hibernate/3
 3 in the directory path corresponds to the slot

In persistence.xml, specify the jboss.as.jpa.providerModule property

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
        <persistence-unit name="example_pu" transaction-type="JTA">
                <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
                <jta-data-source>...</jta-data-source>
                <properties>
                        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:3"/> <!-- module:slot -->
                </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

You may need to specify the older  class (HibernatePersistence) in your persistence.xml as shown above

If your application depends on Hibernate specific classes, you may need to add a dependency on the Hibernate 3 module ().

See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-PackagingtheHibernate3.5orgreater3.xJPApersistenceproviderwithyourapplication

Comment: We've tried whatever you have suggested.But now getting this exception.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

We dont get this exception if we are placing hibernate3.jar in the lib folder of the war.

Comment: I think the Hibernate libraries are messed up due to place in different location of project classpath. Keep all the libraries parallel to module.xml file and remove all libraries from WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: We were able to load all dependencies and got a ClassnotFoundException with freemarker/.....

We tried to add freemarker-2.3.18.jar as a module.
.But we are getting the following exception now.
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class freemarker.template.Configuration